# Scala pass List of Expressions and another Expression as one list to Constructor

Tags: scala, list, parser-combinators

I'm currently writing a `Parser` which extends `JavaTokenParsers` in `Scala` which should amongst other things parse following `Grammar`:

```
list = "[" [ { expr "," } expr ] "]"
```

**My Parser Class**:

```
class ExpParser extends JavaTokenParsers {

  def expr: Parser[Expression] = int | list | bool | id

  [...]    
  private def list: Parser[Liste] = "[" ~> repsep(expr, ",") ~ expr <~ "]"  ^^ {
    case el ~ e => Liste(List(el, e))
  }       // error

  [..]
}

object ParseProgram extends ExpParser {
  def parse(s: String): ParseResult[Expression] = {
    parseAll(expr, s)
  }
}
```

**My Case Class:**

```
sealed trait Expression
[...]
case class Liste(l: List[Expression]) extends Expression
[...]
```

I tried to create a new `List` and pass it to the `Liste Constructor` but i get following error message:

> Type mismatch, expected: List[Expression], actual: List[Object]

So how can i pass the `list` of `Expressions` which i get from `repsep(expr, ",")` and the `expression` which i get from `~ expr` as one `list` to the `Liste Constructor`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`repsep(expr, ",")` gives you a `Parser[List[Expression]]` and isn't that enough?

```
private def list: Parser[Liste] = "[" ~> repsep(expr, ",") <~ "]"  ^^ {
  case el => Liste(el)
}
```

your original parse means to have a list like `[True,FalseTrue]`, is that what you want?

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's absolutely what i want. I think i just thought too complicated